# How do I redirect this URL via htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect all the URLs like this one:

http://example.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=flare_get_counts&url=...

to

http://example.com

How do I do that with a .htaccess redirect so that ALL the URLs with anything after "&url=" get automatically redirected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=flare_get_counts&url=.+
RewriteRule wp-admin/admin-ajax.php /? [R=302,L]
```

You can remove the `302` if the rule works, that will make the redirect permanent.

If you wanted to redirect *any* URL that has a query string containing `url=...`, change the last line to

```
RewriteRule ^ / [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, but what if there are other "actions" by the admin-ajax.php that have "url="? I just want to redirect the ones with "action=flare_get_counts"

Comment: Would something like this work:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} action=flare_get_counts&url=.+
RewriteRule wp-admin/admin-ajax.php / [R=302,L]`

Comment: Yes, that should work. That wasn't clear from your question. Have updated the answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I'll try as soon as I'm home and mark it resolved!

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work... it redirects to `http://example.com/?action=flare_get_counts&url=...`

It just strips away the "wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"...

Any ideas?

Comment: See the latest edit, you need to add a `?` to the rewrite to clear the query string